vim netrw fails to detect or set file type when opening remote file
The problem that is driving me crazy is that when I open a remote file in Vim it fails to detect the filetype, or at least it fails to set it. When the file is opened, it has filetype=netrw, which is wrong. I have gone through this process:

vim -u NONE -U NONE -N # start vim with no plugins,
:set nocompatible.     # set no compatible
:filetype plugin indent on # turn on filetype detection
:syntax enable # enable syntax
:Explore # "Not an editor command" Just prove netrw is not loaded, yet
:source /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim # Now, load it.
:Explore  # Just explore my local home directory
Position the cursor over a Perl file and press Enter. # Open a file for editing
:set filetype # observe that filetype=perl
:Explore scp://self@self.mydomain.com/ # Explore the remote home dir
Position the cursor over a Perl file and press Enter. # Open a file for editing
:set filetype #observe that filetype=netrw

After that I can set the filetype and things will be fine, but the filetype can be lost again after I save the file. This is happening with my system Vim on macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 (the latest). It also was occurring before the update. It's not just for Perl files, it's for any remote file.
So, it's the system Vim, how can I delete that and reinstall it? Or, how can I locate the problem in netrw.vim? Or what can you suggest?
It wasn't like this before some months ago, it had been working for years before that. I don't know what I might have changed or done to cause this.
Thank you.

Open an issue in Vim's issue tracker.

Thanks for the comment, romainl! I looked and found an issue from last week, that showed a patch.
https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/14400
That patch didn't work for me, but I edited it to look like this:
if filereadable(expand("%")) || expand("%") =~# '^\w\+://'
That worked for me, at least once.
